# Ayuda con menú desplegable propiedad trasform:translate

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy intentando hacer un menú desplegable como el que se ve en la imagen.

[image: Img]

Logre que se vea bien en una resolución de 1920 pero cuando agrando o achico el navegador se comporta erróneamente y no lo puedo controlar.
Para poder lograr que el contenedor que esta dentro del `li` productos ocupe la totalidad de la pantalla y no lo tome desde el inicio de la palabra utilicé la propiedad `transform:translate`.
Estoy bastante seguro de que es incorrecto lo que estoy haciendo pero no encuentro la manera de lograr el resultado que se ve en la pantalla de otra forma.

Les dejo la página online: http://www.heist.com.ar/bw3.html

Les dejo el código de la barra de navegación y los estilos del `css`:

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="contenedor-menu">
                    <div id="logo_margenes"><a href="index.html"><img src="imagenes/logo_header.png" alt="logo" title="" id="logo"></a></div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown" id="desplegable menu" ><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">productos</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="submenu">
                                <li class="caja-flexible">
                                    <div class="caja-elementos" >
                                        <dl class="item-flexible">
                                            <dt><strong>Fitness</strong></dt>
                                            <dd><a href="az3.html">AZ3</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="ub3.html">UB3</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="mc2.html">MC2</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="gh2.html">GH2</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="ft1.html">FT1</a></dd>
                                        </dl>

                                        <dl class="item-flexible">
                                            <dt><strong>Triline</strong></dt>
                                            <dd><a href="bw3.html">BW3</a></dd>
                                        </dl>

                                        <dl class="item-flexible">
                                            <dt><strong>Freestyle</strong></dt>
                                            <dd><a href="jr1.html">JR1</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="fs1.html">FS1</a></dd>
                                        </dl>

                                        <dl class="item-flexible">
                                            <dt><strong>Artísticos</strong></dt>
                                            <dd><a href="226e.html">226E</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="22w.html">22W</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="#">316G</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="#">318G</a></dd>
                                        </dl>

                                        <dl class="item-flexible">
                                            <dt><strong>Niños</strong></dt>
                                            <dd><a href="ks1.html">KS1</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="ks2.html">KS2</a></dd>
                                            <dd><a href="cc3.html">CC3</a></dd>
                                        </dl>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>   
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu"><a href="destacados.html">destacados</a></li>
                        <li id="menu"><a href="contacto.html">contacto</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Abajo les dejo los estilos que use para el css

```
/*Estilos del header y el nav*/

#desplegabtextos_esp_ile { position: static }

#submenu  {
    width: 100vw;
}

#submenu .caja-flexible {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50vw;
    /*margin: auto;*/
    margin-left: 43%;
}

.item-flexible {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
}

#logo_margenes {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 320px;
    height: 64px;
}

.container {
    width: 980px; 

}

.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    background: rgba(0, 0,0,0.8);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

#contenedor-menu {
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 95px;
}

.dropdown-menu {    
    background-color: gray;
    background: rgba(0, 0,0,0.8);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    /* font-size: 14px; */
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: none;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175); */
    box-shadow: none; 
    transform: translate(-53.3%);

}

.caja-flexible dt {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}


.caja-flexible dd {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.caja-flexible dd a:hover {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
    color: orange;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.caja-elementos {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Fin del header */
```

Comment: Hola, según has redactado la pregunta, es bastante confusa la información y no tiene el formato adecuado. Edítala e intenta mejorarla.

Comment: Hola. Cómo debería redactarla¿? Cúal es el formato adecuado, donde puedo leer al respecto? Saludos.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es ver como se formatean los datos con markdown cuando escribes la pregunta. 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ahí ví que me sugería varias correcciones, así esta claro o no me estoy explicando bien? Avisame y lo corrijo a ver si puedo ser más específico. Abrazo y disculpa, no tengo mucha experiencia en el sitio.

Comment: Creo que este enlace lo explica mejor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Ya está mejor, vamos a ver si podemos ayudar ahora.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahí leí todo lo que me pasaste.

Comment: Hola, tienes un poco mal planteada la estructura html, por eso tus problemas, mañana con tiempo si nadie responde intentaré ayudarte. Pero lo que yo te recomiendo es que englobes todo en un `div` con `position: absolute` y los 2 menus con un `div` `position: relative` y apartir de ahí empezar a jugar. Todo esto dentro del navbar fixed. Con estas recomendaciones te será mas fàcil trabajar el `css` de tu pagina.

Comment: Hola Arngue, si, yo creo que vengo arrastrando algunos erroresde estructura, pero me cuesta identificarlos. Voy a probar rearmándolo con esos consejos que me diste. Esa propiedad translate que estoy usando nome convence para nada.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba los siguientes cambios en la hoja de estilos para la vista reducida. En `#submenu .caja-flexible` cambia a `margin-left: 0` y en `.dropdown-menu` añade `display: contents`

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 426px) {
    #submenu .caja-flexible {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 90vw;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {display: contents}
}
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la respuesta. A que te referís cuando decís vista reducida?

Comment: Me refería a la vista en resoluciones inferiores.

Comment: Disculpa, no había visto que estaba el código abajo con las resoluciones. Ahí lo probe, pero no cambio mucho. Logro que se vea como quiero en entre 320px y 375px, y entre 375px y 425px. Entre 425 y 768 se ve muy mal y después varía a medida que va subiendo. Creo que todo tiene que ver con la propiedad translate que estoy usando, pero no se como resolverlo de otra forma.